# Number of cores used by snapcraft when building snap

Tags: snap, packaging, multipass

I am using [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/) to build chromium.

I see that it creates a VM with [Multipass](https://multipass.run/).

```
$ snapcraft 
Support for 'multipass' needs to be set up. Would you like to do it now? [y/N]: Y
...
multipass 1.10.1 from Canonical✓ installed
Waiting for multipass...
Launching a VM.
Launched: snapcraft-chromium
```

It then proceeds to install an OS, fetch sources, patch sources and build chromium.

However, I noticed that while building, it never uses more than 2 cores.

Is that because the VM has assigned 2 cores to it?

Is there a way to tell snapcraft or multipass that it can use all cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable `SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_CPU` before building.

From the [source](https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/9d353a6305b8006e0bc0e984c87591e5f08fb09d/snapcraft/internal/build_providers/_multipass/_multipass.py#L91):

```
cpus = _MachineSetting(envvar="SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_CPU", default="2")
mem = _MachineSetting(envvar="SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_MEMORY", default="2G")
```

And the wiki:

> SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_CPU
>
> The allocated processor cores for the VM build environment
>
> Default value: 2
>
> NOTE: This environment variable is only honored when the VM is not
> created yet